# (Javascript) Rock, scissors, paper. The random function is not working as expected

Tags: javascript

It's my first time posting on this website.

At the moment I'm trying to build the rock, scissors, paper game on Javascript. I've already written out the code, however I have a problem running the code.

Whenever I refresh the browser to play the game, the console.log at the bottom will run the game but the computerPlay() will always be scissors. I've tried running computerPlay() on it's own which works properly.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
        let userPlay;
        do {
            userPlay = prompt("rock, paper, or scissors?");
        }
        while (userPlay !== "rock" && userPlay !== "paper" && userPlay !== "scissors"); //prompt user for rock, scissors, or paper.

        let compPlay = computerPlay();

        function computerPlay() { //computer generates a random answer.
            let random = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
            return random[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

        }
        function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) { //plays a round of the game.
            if (playerSelection === "rock") {
                if (computerSelection === "rock") {
                    return "Draw!";
                } else if (computerSelection === "paper") {
                    return "You lose! Paper beats rock.";
                } else {
                    return "You win! Rock beats scissors.";
                }
            } else if (playerSelection === "paper") {
                if (computerSelection === "rock") {
                    return "You win! Paper beats rock.";
                } else if (computerSelection === "paper") {
                    return "Draw!";
                } else {
                    return "You lose! Scissors beats paper.";
                }
            } else {
                if (computerSelection === "rock") {
                    return "You lose! Rock beats scissors.";
                } else if (computerSelection === "paper") {
                    return "You win! Scissors beats paper.";
                } else {
                    return "Draw!";
                }
            }
        }

        console.log(playRound(userPlay, computerPlay));
```

Comment: `computerPlay` is a function, not a string, you forgot to invoke it. Consider using precise variable names to avoid these sorts of mistakes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using different variable names for the same thing `computerSelection` in one place, `compPlay` in another. Finally, in the `console.log()` at the end of the program, you are printing out the function `computerPlay`.

try this:

```
   let userPlay = 'scissors';
         do {
            userPlay = prompt("rock, paper, or scissors?");
        }
        while (userPlay !== "rock" && userPlay !== "paper" && userPlay !== "scissors"); //prompt user for rock, scissors, or paper.

        let computerSelection = computerPlay();

        function computerPlay() { //computer generates a random answer.
            let random = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
            return random[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

        }
        function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) { //plays a round of the game.
            if (playerSelection === "rock") {
                if (computerSelection === "rock") {
                    return "Draw!";
                } else if (computerSelection === "paper") {
                    return "You lose! Paper beats rock.";
                } else {
                    return "You win! Rock beats scissors.";
                }
            } else if (playerSelection === "paper") {
                if (computerSelection === "rock") {
                    return "You win! Paper beats rock.";
                } else if (computerSelection === "paper") {
                    return "Draw!";
                } else {
                    return "You lose! Scissors beats paper.";
                }
            } else {
                if (computerSelection === "rock") {
                    return "You lose! Rock beats scissors.";
                } else if (computerSelection === "paper") {
                    return "You win! Scissors beats paper.";
                } else {
                    return "Draw!";
                }
            }
        }

        console.log(playRound(userPlay, computerSelection));
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. The asker is a new user and I helped him by spotting his error.

Comment: It wasn't me, but these sorts of questions are off-topic and are not going to be of use to anyone in the future - better to close and delete than to answer. It's not only better for the site, I've seen that such answers usually attract downvotes too